# Calling a controller action with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, hyperlink

After playing around with links in Rails for a view hours i've managed to actually get a link to invoke a method in my controller. But i still don't understand why all my other attempts failed. Im hoping you could help me out with that.

I have the scaffold "Cars". When in the show view for a car, id like to click a link that invokes the method "drive" in my Car controller.

**This WORKS:** `<%= link_to "Drive", drive_car_path(@car) %>`

It seems this only works if i have this is my routes.rb:

```
resources :cars do
  member do
    get 'drive'
  end
end
```

Why does `<%= link_to "Drive", car_path, :method => :drive %>` not work?

Do I need to put a `GET` in the `routes.rb` file for every method I create in my controller?

I can't seem to find any sites explain how to use links together with routes. They only seem to come separate. Do you guys have any easily understandable tutorials on this?

Comment: From the command line, try "rake routes" to see what your options are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `link_to "Drive", :controller => "car", :action => "drive"`

Also, `method` is for choosing the HTTP method (GET, POST, ...). It's not `method` as in routine.

Be sure to check out [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [The Lowdown on Routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/), they're both awesome resources.

Comment: Of course, I was just waiting to see if somebody else had something to contribute. Tank you.